# WooCommerce login redirect based on cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I want to apply following 2 case :

- If User not logged in and cart is empty: Then redirect user to login and then my account
- If User not logged in and cart has product: Then redirect user to login and after login redirect to checkout

My Code :

```
 function wpse_Nologin_redirect() {

    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        $MyLoginURL = "http://example.in/my-account/";
        wp_redirect($MyLoginURL);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_Nologin_redirect');
```

Above code is working fine for my first case. But for my second case, when I check cart with **`if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) == 0 ) {}`**, my site stops working.

I have added this code in my theme's functions.php file.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **To avoid your site to be off,** `global $woocommerce;` is missing. 
>   Now `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->cart` is now simply replaced by `WC()->cart`.
>
> **To check if cart is empty**, you should use [**`WC()->cart->is_empty()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_is_empty), as [**`is_empty()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_is_empty) is a conditional method of [**`WC_cart` class**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html).
>
> After, on **checkout page** (in both cases) if user is not logged in, you want to redirect him to **my_account** page (login/create account area).
>
> Now on **my_account page**, when a logged user has something in his cart, you want to redirect him on checkout page.

Here is the code you need:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woocommerce_custom_redirections');
function woocommerce_custom_redirections() {
    // Case1: Non logged user on checkout page (cart empty or not empty)
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() )
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );

    // Case2: Logged user on my account page with something in cart
    if( is_user_logged_in() && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_account_page() )
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme.* Tested and works.

---

Reference *(Woocommerce documentation)*:

- [Woocommerce Class `WC_Cart` — **`is_empty()` method**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_is_empty)
- [WooCommerce Available conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-2)

Comment: Thanks a  lot. I am not expert in woocommere and was trying to achieve it since last 2 days :) You rock....

Comment: I found as non-logged in users redirect to login and after logged in customer will redirect to checkout page if cart having product at that place it's working fine.

But if anyone clicking on My account link or order link also then again it"ll redirect customer to checkout only until carts become empty. So you can't open My Account links or Order links etc.

Is it possible to track the path, means if customer trying to login after redirecting from checkout to login page and then only redirect to checkout page and for others customer who are normally login they will see my account page.

Comment: @RaviShankar My answer here is just answering the OP's question and works for that. Now you can ask a new question with a link to this answer thread, explaining everything.

Comment: Posted, need help

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071005/woocommerce-login-redirect-based-on-cart-and-based-on-path)

Comment: Redirects you right back to checkout if you are logged in and try to navigate to "my account"

Comment: I am getting the message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Does anybody faced the same issue?

Comment: How to prevent infinite loops and undesired redirects? This should be properly handled by tested code in WooCommerce core, not by some lines of code pasted from StackOverflow. Don't use in production!