# Non logged in users Woocommerce, redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a shop online with Woocommerce, where my client ask me he don't want people to be able to register, he will create a user and password for each one of his clients. That way he can control who buys on his shop.

So I went into Woocommerce and disable the registration at checkout and everywhere, and the option to allow guests to place orders. Everything works fine, except that when someone tries to place an order, when logged out, when he tries to go to the checkout page, it just shows an unformatted message saying "You must be logged in to place an order". Is there a way where I can redirect not logged in customers to login page, when trying to access checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this code could be more compact, simple and convenient:

```
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout())
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

---

Reference: [WooCommerce login redirect based on cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355976/woocommerce-login-redirect-based-on-cart/39357627#39357627)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_user_to_login_page' );

function redirect_user_to_login_page(){
    // Make sure your checkout page slug is correct
    if( is_page('checkout') ) {
        if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // Make sure your login page slug is correct in below line
            wp_redirect('/my-account/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and mine?? is just curiosity

Comment: Nothing major. I just posted my answer without realising you have already got a solution. Only its cleaner I guess, but yours is perfect too. I don't know if I should remove my answer or not.

Comment: I used your code, and it crashed XD so .. either i paste it wrong or your code is buggy XD

Comment: Okay. I tested the same on my local server and it worked. So not sure why it crashed on yours. Moreover the first condition makes sure you are on checkout page. So still no chance if your checkout page is any different. If you just want to try, try using the exit statement just like u didi in your version.

Comment: Sorry beleive it or not, i pasted it wrong so it does not crash.. BUT... the redirection it maskes is wrong, as it redirects to:

www.example.com/checkout/my-account

instead of www.example.com/my-account

Comment: Ok, found out the problem on your code.. you have to add wp_redirect('/my-account/') instead of wp_redirect('my-account')

Comment: believe it or not, its working on my local machine. I am curious why its different. can you share the full url of login page

Comment: It might be cause my installation of wordpress is under a subfolder in the server. But... if you change the code to what i suggested, I guess you could have a more "universal" code. The full URL would be something like this www.testingserver.com/companyname/my-account/

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it my self! But still if someone has a cleaner code to do so, I'm open to suggestions.

What I did was to paste the following code on the functions.php file of the child theme:

```html
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in()
{

    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout())
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url('/my-account/')
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks
kind regards

Comment: If you are going to use the code above, remember to change the /my-account/ to what ever is your login page.