# Redirect to login (my-account) before checkout and return to checkout after login - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect non logged in users to login before checkout and return them back to checkout after login/registered

Based on *[WooCommerce login redirect based on cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355976/woocommerce-login-redirect-based-on-cart/39357627#39357627)* answer code, here is my code that redirects the user to the My Account page if not logged in.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woocommerce_custom_redirections');
function woocommerce_custom_redirections() {
   
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() )
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
}
```

I need an extra argument to redirect them back based on the previous page they come from (checkout page) after the user logged in/registered.

In case someone logged in from directly from my-account not based on checkout page they login normally to my account page and don't get redirected to checkout even if the cart not empty.

Comment: Try using local storage, to save last url, before the redirect and check it for a relevant value after they;ve logged in.

Comment: Do you have any example how to do it, I don't know alot about php. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `session_start()` on the checkout page `global $wp; $_SESSION["checkout_url"] =  home_url( $wp->request )` then you can retrieve that when redirecting after login is sucessful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but this is what you need:

```html
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in()
{
    $pageid = get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' );
   if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url('/my-account/') // your my acount url
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```